# How eluvial process determines the difference in colour of soil layers

Tags: soil, soil-science

How eluvial process determines the colour of E horizon lighter compared to O horizon?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between eluvium and alluvium?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/2901/what-is-the-difference-between-eluvium-and-alluvium)

Comment: What do E and O stand for?  Maybe we can try to help make clearer what you're asking.

Comment: @SudheerMuthusamy Question is on topic AFAIK but the way you have written it makes it unclear. If you can clarify what those terms mean and adding a few references I (and maybe others) can reopen the question

Comment: The designations of soil horizons as E and O are standardized in several classification systems but it would help to define them. The eluvial horizon, or E horizon, occurs in some soils where strong leaching of clay minerals, oxides, and organic material leaves pale colored mineral grains. The O horizon is the uppermost layer containing large amounts of organic matter so it is dark. The Wikipedia  "Soil Horizon" article is pretty good.