# What are the differences between alluvial, eluvial and colluvial deposits?

Tags: geology, sedimentology, terminology, mining

There's always confusion and disagreement when these terms are mentioned. Need to be sure of their exact meanings.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is almost a duplicate of [What is the difference between eluvium and alluvium?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/2901/94), but you also ask about colluvial deposits. The [accepted answer](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/2903/94) for that question references [this convenient guide](https://australianmuseum.net.au/geological-ore-deposits) from the Australian Museum, which also covers colluvial deposits:

> Alluvial: Detrital material which is transported by a river and usually deposited along the river's pathway, either in the riverbed itself or on its floodplain.
>
> Colluvial: Weathered material transported by gravity action such as on scree slopes.
>
> Eluvial: Weathered material still at or near its point of formation.